# Same data being returned by linq for 2 different executions of a stored procedure?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a stored procedure that I am calling through Entity Framework.

The stored procedure has 2 date parameters. I supply different argument in the 2 times I call the stored procedure. I have verified using SQL Profiler that the stored procedure is being called correctly and returning the correct results.

When I call my method the second time with different arguments, even though the stored procedure is bringing back the correct results, the table created contains the same data as the first time I called it.

```
dtStart = 01/08/2009  
dtEnd = 31/08/2009

public List<dataRecord> GetData(DateTime dtStart, DateTime dtEnd)
{
  var tbl = from t in db.SP(dtStart, dtEnd)                       
                      select t;
  return tbl.ToList();            
}

GetData((new DateTime(2009, 8, 1), new DateTime(2009, 8, 31))
// tbl.field1 value = 45450 - CORRECT

GetData(new DateTime(2009, 7, 1), new DateTime(2009, 7, 31))
// tbl.field1 value = 45450 - WRONG 27456 expected
```

Is this a case of Entity Framework being clever and caching?  I can't see why it would cache this though as it has executed the stored procedure twice.

Do I have to do something to close `tbl`?

- using Visual Studio 2008 + Entity Framework.
- I also get the message "query cannot be enumerated more than once" a few times every now and then, am not sure if that is relevant?

FULL CODE LISTING

```
namespace ProfileDataService
{
    public partial class DataService
    {

        public static List<MeterTotalConsumpRecord> GetTotalAllTimesConsumption(DateTime dtStart, DateTime dtEnd, EUtilityGroup ug, int nMeterSelectionType, int nCustomerID, 
                                                 int nUserID, string strSelection, bool bClosedLocations, bool bDisposedLocations)
        {    
            dbChildDataContext db = DBManager.ChildDataConext(nCustomerID);

            var tbl = from t in db.GetTotalConsumptionByMeter(dtStart, dtEnd, (int) ug, nMeterSelectionType, nCustomerID, nUserID, strSelection, bClosedLocations, bDisposedLocations, 1)                       
                      select t;

            return tbl.ToList();            
        }
}
}

/// CALLER

List<MeterTotalConsumpRecord> _P1Totals;
List<MeterTotalConsumpRecord> _P2Totals;

 public void LoadData(int nUserID, int nCustomerID, ELocationSelectionMethod locationSelectionMethod, string strLocations, bool bIncludeClosedLocations, bool bIncludeDisposedLocations,
            DateTime dtStart, DateTime dtEnd, ReportsBusinessLogic.Lists.EPeriodType durMainPeriodType, ReportsBusinessLogic.Lists.EPeriodType durCompareToPeriodType, ReportsBusinessLogic.Lists.EIncreaseReportType rptType,
            bool bIncludeDecreases)
{

   ///Code for setting properties using parameters..        

  _P2Totals = ProfileDataService.DataService.GetTotalAllTimesConsumption(_P2StartDate, _P2EndDate, EUtilityGroup.Electricity, 1, nCustomerID, nUserID, strLocations,
                bIncludeClosedLocations, bIncludeDisposedLocations);

  _P1Totals = ProfileDataService.DataService.GetTotalAllTimesConsumption(_StartDate, _EndDate, EUtilityGroup.Electricity, 1, nCustomerID, nUserID, strLocations, 
                bIncludeClosedLocations, bIncludeDisposedLocations);


  PopulateLines() //This fills up a list of objects with information for my report ready for the totals to be added

  PopulateTotals(_P1Totals, 1);
  PopulateTotals(_P2Totals, 2);

}


 void PopulateTotals(List<MeterTotalConsumpRecord> objTotals, int nPeriod)
 {
        MeterTotalConsumpRecord objMeterConsumption = null;

        foreach (IncreaseReportDataRecord objLine in _Lines)
        {
            objMeterConsumption = objTotals.Find(delegate(MeterTotalConsumpRecord t) { return t.MeterID == objLine.MeterID; });

            if (objMeterConsumption != null)
            {
                if (nPeriod == 1)
                {
                    objLine.P1Consumption = (double)objMeterConsumption.Consumption;
                }
                else
                {
                    objLine.P2Consumption = (double)objMeterConsumption.Consumption;
                }

                objMeterConsumption = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried my best to edit this, but honestly, I'm having a really hard time figuring out what's going on here.  You might want to post an actual working code example instead of bits and pieces here and there.

Comment: Thanks you have edited it well!

When I call GetData for August 2009 I get the number I am expecting - 45450

When I call GetData for July 2009 I also get 45450.  This is wrong, I am expecting to get 27456

The exact error message that I am getting occasionally is 

System.InvalidOperationException : The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once.

Not sure if that has anything to do with it?

Comment: Paul, that doesn't help, you've just repeated the information you already gave us.  For one thing, `GetData` gives back a **list**, and you're telling us the result of a single record, which doesn't make sense.  And there's nowhere near enough code here to attempt to track down the source of that error message - it happens when you try to reuse the results of a query.  Please, as stated earlier, post a *complete* code sample that reproduces your issue.

Comment: Is the "db" variable a static member scope variable?

Comment: I believe so, have just added a full code listing

Comment: This is cache related - looks like the second call returns the same meters as the first so linq does not update the objects

How do I free the cache?

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing the DataService class to look like this:

```
public partial class DataService
{
    public List<MeterTotalConsumpRecord> 
                      GetTotalAllTimesConsumption(SearchCriteria sc)
    {    
        var db = new dbChildDataContext(); // new every time, just in this test case.

        var totalConsumption = db.GetTotalConsumptionByMeter(sc.DtStart, 
                                                             sc.DtEnd, 
                                                             sc.ug, 
                                                             sc.MeterSelectionType, 
                                                             sc.CustomerID, 
                                                             sc.UserID, 
                                                             sc.Selection, 
                                                             sc.ClosedLocations, 
                                                             sc.DisposedLocations, 1)
                                 .ToList();                       

        //inspect how many results are returned.
        int rowCount = totalConsumption.Count;


        return totalConsumption;

    }
} 


//use objects to pass between classes
public class SearchCriteria
{
    public DateTime DtStart {get;set;}
    public DateTime DtEnd {get;set;}
    public int ug {get;set;}
    public int MeterSelectionType {get;set;}
    public int CustomerID {get;set;}
    public int UserID {get;set;}
    public string Selection {get;set;}
    public bool ClosedLocations {get;set;}
    public bool DisposedLocations  {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but is there no way of avoiding creating a new context?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar problem in my project, and in my case it was the duplicate Id problem, Id of entities returned from stored procedure was actually just order of the entities so they weren't unique in 2 query results

I figured out 2 key points :

- 2 query result entities that have the exact same Id, will have duplicate values on properties too
- this is also true for single query result that has entities with same Id